# Command working in command prompt doesn't work in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, cmd, command-line

I am trying to run a command using the C# namespace `System.Diagnostics`.

I use these commands to install SQL Server and SQL Server Management Studio.

For SQL Server, I downloaded the installer from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=55994 and installed the basic version.

After that I want to use this:

```
try
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\SQLServer2017Media\\Express_ENU\\SETUP.exe /Q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION=install /FEATURES=SQL,AS,IS,Tools /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER";

    p.Start();
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

This command works in `cmd.exe`:

```
C:\SQLServer2017Media\Express_ENU\setup.exe /Q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS 
    /ACTION=install /FEATURES=SQL,AS,IS,Tools /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER
```

I downloaded the installer for SQL Server Management Studio from https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/D/4/DD495084-ADA7-4827-ADD3-FC566EC05B90/SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe

and run:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "start \"\" " + DownloadsFolderPath + "\\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe /install /Passive SSMSInstallRoot=C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server /norestart";
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

By cmd:

```
start "" C:\Users\...\Downloads\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe /install /Passive 
         SSMSInstallRoot=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server /norestart
```

The command in works in `cmd.exe`. In Visual Studio it doesn't. I open Visual Studio with administrator privileges. In two cases it never returns from

```
output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Documentation for SQL Server installation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-ver15#Feature

SQL Server Management Studio installation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Prefix the argument with "/K" to see if there is some kind of error. /K keeps the console open even after the command has completed

Comment: Your code looks like a word macro. Try starting SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe directly without all the outer cmd and start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because you are not using "/C" in your argument but a "start".

It's a little diffrent from CMD line

try like that instead:

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C \"\" " + DownloadsFolderPath + "\\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe /install /Passive SSMSInstallRoot=C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server /norestart";
```

Comment: "\\EkGrafConveyors.d

Comment: maybe you better look carfully your escaped caracter ?